# How to get RadioGroup checked state in Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, radio-group

Before asking this question I have searched for it, there are plenty of solutions for it but that are not what I want.
I have a RecyclerView with a RadioGroup with 3 Buttons . I want to get the `checkedState` of its childeren. I don't want it to get in `onBindViewHolder` by applying `onCheckedStateChangeListener`, I want to collect all checked and unchecked states with a button in activity e.g. `onCheckedStateChangeListener` works only with someone changes the state but I want to get data without any such listener , I am unable to figure out how to apply this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a RadioGroup in each row of your recycler view?  Otherwise you don't really need the recycler, just use the radio group directly.

But for each row in `onBindViewHolder` use `onCheckedStateChangeListener` to update your model objects that are backing your `RecyclerView`.  Then when your button is pressed you can get the adapter from the `RecyclerView` and loop through each model to find which item is selected.

Comment: If not button is checked then?? If not Button is checked `onCheckedStateChangeListener` will be null.

Comment: If no button is checked than you are right `onCheckedStateChangeListener` will never be called; however, since it's never called your model won't be updated and you can check `if(myModel.getCheckedObject() == null) { displayError(); }`